# Heap Allocation function hits wall: EXC BAD ACCESS CODE 1

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

I am using dynamic heap allocation to create a classroom tool to add students. The program prompts the user/teacher for the names of students, and assigns them to an array.

I tested the `while` loop that calls the `add` function responsible for allocating a bigger heap array. the program outputs the list of students added as expected and can create a bigger heap array.

However, when I try to add an 11th student, I get this message `THRD 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS code1`. I read this means the program can no longer access the memory block, but am confused as to why this happens at the 11th student? Any recommendations for debugging are very appreciated. Thanks for your patience, I'm still getting used to C++

```
/*
Dynamic Heap Allocation using pointers
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void add(string arr[],int& studs,int& counter){
    //copies student names to a bigger array
    studs+=10; //vs passing by value
    string* big_brotha = new string[studs]; // a holder
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++){
        big_brotha[i]=arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    arr = big_brotha;
}


int main() {
    int n=5;
    int count=0;
    string name;
    bool cont = true;
    char option;
    string* arrayofpointers = new string[n];
    cout << "enter student names. Enter Q to quit " << endl;
    while (cont){
        cout << "enter student name for seat number " << count << endl;
        cin >> name;
        if (name=="Q"){
            for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
                cout << arrayofpointers[i] << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
        cout << "is the counter less than array size? " <<  (count<n) << endl;
        if (count>=n){ //time to make the array bigger!
            cout << "time to make the array bigger!" << endl;
            add(arrayofpointers,n,count);
            cout << "the array is now this big " << n << endl;
            arrayofpointers[count]=name;


        }
        else{
            arrayofpointers[count]=name; //no longer possible to access memory
        }

        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case 'arrayofpointers' is **copied** into your function as 'arr'. you delete its contents (getting rid of what it had been pointing to) and then assign it a new value. But, you assign the value to 'arr', not to the arrayofpointers. Therefore the next operation on the arrayofpointers will reference deleted memory.

what you really need is something like this:

```
void add(string *&arr,int& studs,int& counter){
```

This would create a reference to a pointer.

or this:

```
void add(string **arr,int& studs,int& counter){
```

which is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: aah i see, so i need a pointer to a pointer because arr is not passed as a pointer. the arrayofpointers is deleted after the function call, and only has space for five elements. Thanks!

Comment: btw I tried your suggestions and got an error for each one: `arr declared as array of references of type string *&` for reference to a pointer and `no viable overloaded =` for pointer to a pointer

Comment: the error for which line? If you use '**' than you have to pass address of the pointer to the line: add(&arrayofpointers,n,count); and use star in here '*arr = big_brotha'; if you use '*&' it should work as is.

Comment: and for '**' you also need this:  big_brotha[i]=(*arr)[i];

Comment: thanks I made it work with a single asterick: 
`void add(string *arr[],int& studs,int& counter){
    //copies student names to a bigger array
    studs+=10; //vs passing by value
    string* big_brotha = new string[studs]; // a holder
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++){
        big_brotha[i]=(*arr)[i];
    }
    delete[] *arr;
    *arr = big_brotha;
}
`

Comment: this is not right. You just declared an array of 'string *' in the argument. It is not the same as a pointer to pointer, You might be lucky and it could work by coincident.. Try to run valgrind on it. You really need pointer to a pointer (or a reference to a pointer).